# Does each GAE instance have its own memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I would like to know if each GAE instance has its own memcache and if data which is cached from one instance is reachable from another instance? Or if it needs a new query again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GAE: memcache: is it the same across multiple app instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055381/gae-memcache-is-it-the-same-across-multiple-app-instances)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, memcache is not per instance, it is global to your app. So yes, every instance can access the memcache independently from the instance.

Comment: Ok but pricing for memcache not mentioned on documentation. What is the limit for it, if it's not consuming instance's ram. (I mean total limit not for a key)

Comment: Memcache is free to use. There are limits to daily usage of memcache, but they are not officially published: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175586/how-much-memory-of-memcache-is-available-to-a-google-app-engine-account