# In a logic view perspective, it a "one" (and consistent) memcached server by app?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

It's a question about GAE behind the scene.

ok, it can be a silly question, but I want figure out how google can support geographic distributed datacenters and what strategies used in memcached in this case.

**In a logic view perspective, it a "one" (and consistent) memcached server by app?** Let me explain: one of most knowed cases to use memcached is a "Page View Count" sample. Well, if memcached is distributed/replicated (that is, the key:value will be distributed and replicated in n+1 machines) I can't guarantee a consistent value (or something like this), because the count value will be divide by n+1.

Another case that a distributed/replicated memcached can result in troubles: I would use some not updated entity value. 
ex: 
step 1. req webserver1+memcached1 (do some queries and cache entity1 in memcached1)
step 2. req webserver2+memcached2 (update entity1 and invalidate it in memcached2)
step 3. req webserver1+memcached1 (get entity1 from memcached1, but it's a old data, because it was updated in datastore, invalidated in memcached2 but NOT in memcached1!!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055381/gae-memcache-is-it-the-same-across-multiple-app-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **single** memcache is shared across all instances of your application.

It does not matter what instance puts a value in or gets it out, they all share the same storage.

So yes, it's by app.

Comment: Even if it's geo distributed app? (ex.: EU and USA)

Comment: An app can only be in one or the other data centre locations, not both. You choose. So it simply does not come up - there is no need to sync memcache. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/location.